# How to test a property on the res.locals object

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, httpresponse

Is there a way to assert the value of a property on res.locals? For example consider:

```
        res.locals.authenticated = false;
        res.render('index');
```

Now to test this:

```
        expect(res.status).to.equal(200);
        expect(res.locals.authenticated).to.be.false
```

I get a type error **Cannot read property 'authenticated' of undefined**

How can I test a property I pass to res.locals?

Here is the full code:

```
router.get('/', function (req, res) {

        res.locals.authenticated = false;
        res.render('index');

});
```

And I'm testing with Mocha, chai, and chai-http:

```
it('should respond with contents of the homepage', function (done) {

    chai.request(server).get('/').end(function (err, res) {
        expect(err).to.be.null;
        expect(res.status).to.equal(200);
        expect(res.locals.authenticated).to.be.false;
        expect(res).to.be.html;
        done();
    });
});
```

Comment: I see no reason why you should't be able. But it seems that in your case `res.locals` is not defined. Can you share the flow?

Comment: @YoniLevy I added the entire snippet above. Keep in mind that everything works, I just want my tests to pass.

Comment: Looking at the docs (http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.locals) it seems that `res.locals` is only visible to the view(s) rendered, So testing it in `end` probably won't get you far. You may need to hack your way into the rendering engine but it seems like a poor solution.

Comment: So is there any way to test the properties of res.locals then ?

Comment: Not that I know of but then again I didn't really dig in to it.

Comment: See if you indeed get `res.locals` in your view

Comment: rec.locals is not accessible where you need it.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/26811414/387094 for a pretty good explanation of why.